# Golang Bufio writer .Flush() does not write small data when big buffer size

Tags: go

Golang Bufio writer .Flush() does not write small data when big buffer size (example 4096(standard size)*2)

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "bufio"
)
func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("test")
    defer file.Close()
    w := bufio.NewWriter(file)

    w = bufio.NewWriterSize(
        w,
        4096*2,
    )
    bytesAvailable := w.Available()
    log.Printf("Available %v\n", bytesAvailable)
    bw, _ := w.Write(
      []byte("A"),
    )
    log.Printf("written bytes: %v\n", bw)
    bytesAvailable = w.Available()
    log.Printf("Available: %v\n", bytesAvailable)
    buf := w.Buffered()
    log.Printf("buffered: %d\n", buf)
    err = w.Flush()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

When I use the standard size or I write more data it works as expected.

Comment: What do you expect to see, and what happens instead? You're not checking the buffered data after flush in this example. This works as expected: https://play.golang.org/p/v2wDgGJIiq

Comment: Output:
2017/12/18 16:37:39 Available 8192
2017/12/18 16:37:39 written bytes: 1
2017/12/18 16:37:39 Available: 8191
2017/12/18 16:37:39 buffered: 1
$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stingo stingo 0 dic 18 16:37 test

Comment: I'm not sure what to make from that comment, please format in your question.

Comment: Sorry I was adding more data.
File is created but nothing is added to it.
I believe Flush() should write "A".
Thanks.

Comment: Please look at this: https://play.golang.org/p/-qCC4Zl-Es
I have modified your example and nothing is being written even Flush() is executed.

Comment: No, `Flush` has nothing to do with the underlying file. If you want to ensure that the data is written to storage, you need to fall [`File.Sync()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Sync) and remove the doubled up buffer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the application has two layers of bufio writers:

```
w := bufio.NewWriter(file)
w = bufio.NewWriterSize(
    w,
    4096*2,
)
```

One bufio.Writer wraps the other.  The application flushes the outer bufio.Writer, but there's no code that flushes the inner bufio.Writer.   Change the code to use a single bufio.Writer and the program will work as expected.

```
w := bufio.NewWriterSize(
    file,
    4096*2,
)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing the `Sync()` call to the file pointer, so the file is not written to the file system; `Flush()` will just pass the buffer to the file writer, but then you need to push the file to the disk.

See [src/os/file_posix.go#L120](https://golang.org/src/os/file_posix.go?s=3352:3379#L120) and [pkg/bufio/#Writer.Flush](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Writer.Flush)

Comment: I tried and still the same issue.
Even with bytes buffer I am having the same issue.
Please see: https://play.golang.org/p/-qCC4Zl-Es